# Regex PHP how to match tag followed by

Tags: php, html, regex

I can't find a solution to this problem:
I want to match all text between  tags and followed by 4 numbers inside ( ).
 Exg.
I want to match this:

```
<i>Alien - Resurrection </i> (1997)
<i>Alien - Resurrection </i>(1997)
<i>Alien - Resurrection </i>
(1997)
```

Now if it founds:

```
<li> Alien -Resurrection </i> bla bla bla <i> Alien the first one </i> (1991)
```

It matches the whole string, 
but i would like it to only match the

```
<i> Alien the first one </i> (1991)
```

The strict rule is that after the  tag there must 4 digits into brackets ()

My regular expression now looks like this:

```
/<i>(.*?)<\/i> \(([0-9]*)\)/s
```

Comment: Any opportunity to post a link to the greatest answer on SO ever... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors..

```
/^<i>([\s\S]*?)<\/i>\s*\(([0-9]{4})\)$/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qJ3nR3/1)

Comment: Close, but i think i didn't explain very well. The problem is that now, my regex it matches this:<li> Alien -Resurrection </i> bla bla bla <i> Alien the first one </i> (1991) but i would like it to only match the  <i> Alien the first one </i> (1991). The strict rule is that after the </i> tag there must 4 digits into brackets ()

Comment: Just remove ^ and $ from the regex